# How to dispose heavy set of static variable and collection?

Tags: c#

I made a big windows app, and in the program.cs class i am using a lot to static variables
around 20 and some of these are used for big collection of object that i make during the process.

I want to know how should i mange this in the finish of application where and how should i call them dispose. I made `GC.Collect` but that hangs application and degrade the performance.
 And when i dint call `GC.Collect` it was giving memory lick and hanging for long.

Please let me know how should i manage this static class, static variables. So that performance boost.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the .NET memory model, if you want to manually manage resource lifetimes use C++ or C

Answer (score 4):

I think the way you are using the `static` variables is completely wrong, you might have misunderstood the concept.

You should mark any field as `static` only when you know, variables will be accessed through out the life of program i.e. they will be GC'ed only when you terminate the program.

**EDIT** In C# the memory is automatically managed by the `Garbage Collector`, the programmer need to know only that when an object which is created is applicable for Garbage Collection. In [MSDN ducumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138(v=vs.71).aspx) it is clearly mentioned,

> C# employs automatic memory management, which frees developers from manually allocating and freeing the memory occupied by objects. Automatic memory management policies are implemented by a garbage collector. The memory management life cycle of an object is as follows:
>
> 1. When the object is created, memory is allocated for it, the constructor is run, and the object is considered live.
> 2. If the object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of execution, other than the running of destructors, the object is considered no longer in use, and it becomes eligible for destruction. The C# compiler and the garbage collector may choose to analyze code to determine which references to an object may be used in the future. For instance, if a local variable that is in scope is the only existing reference to an object, but that local variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of execution from the current execution point in the procedure, the garbage collector may (but is not required to) treat the object as no longer in use.
> 3. Once the object is eligible for destruction, at some unspecified later time the destructor (Section 10.12) (if any) for the object is run. Unless overridden by explicit calls, the destructor for the object is run once only.
> 4. Once the destructor for an object is run, if that object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of execution, including the running of destructors, the object is considered inaccessible and the object becomes eligible for collection.
> 5. Finally, at some time after the object becomes eligible for collection, the garbage collector frees the memory associated with that object.

**In simple words, if an object has no more live references (pointers whose scope has not ended) which are pointing to it, it is eligible for GC.**

In your case the **static variables** are are having the  scope which extends across the entire run of the program and once you remove those references either by assigning those to new objects or assigning them to `null` then old objects will be applicable for GC if no other live references pointing to old objects are alive.

Comment: In my application those variables are being used through the program that is why i used them.

Comment: Program termination mean closing the EXE, i am concern if for 1 order item i am managing these then for another order item how to dispose and remove all changes to them and make them default.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet, that's why they should not be static.  If you want to replace them with different values to use in a  different context, those should be instance variables on the context that might change.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet can you provide the information what are those static varaibles, if you are having list of items then just clearing the list and adding new elements when you have new orders will also clear the memory,

Answer (score 1):

You have `IDisposable` objects (Forms and Controls, I'm guessing) and need to dispose them at some appropriate time.  **The best way** to solve this is going to be to create an object model appropriate to your domain, and have it manage them. I don't know about your domain, so it's hard to give details about that.

To make it more convenient, you could group these variables together in one class.  Instead of holding these variables in the `Program` class, put them in another class that `Program` references, and make that class `IDisposable`.  Something like this:

```
public class Resources : IDisposable
{
    public MyForm MyForm {get;set;}
    public MyControl MyControl {get;set;}
    //etc...
    public void Dispose()
    {
         if(MyForm != null)
              MyForm.Dispose()

         if(MyControl != null)
              MyControl.Dispose()

         //etc..
    }
}
```

If the problem with this is that you want to avoid bugs around accessing Disposed objects, **don't make them static!**  If they are not static, you can control what object bind to them more clearly, and make sure those object stop holding a reference to them when they are disposed.